# MomentJS is sometimes adding the wrong amount of hours

Tags: javascript, angular, time, momentjs

So what i'm simply trying to achieve a feature where i add X.X amount of hours to a 24h time. The issue is for the time 00:00, an incorrect amount of hours is added

The code i wrote works for the most part. It works for every possible time except 0:00.
If i have 01:30 and i add 1h it gives me 02:30. If I have 02:30 and i add 1.5h it gives me 04:00.

So heres this issue. When i have 00:00 and i add 1h i get 01:06...seems to make no sense and i was hoping someone with more momentJS experience might have some thoughts or ideas on the matter. Heres the code

If i have 00:00 and have 3.5 i get 03:06. This all only seems to happen when i start with 00:00. Kind of driving me crazy

```
console.log(timesheetRows[i][p]); //prints 0:00
console.log(Number(hours)); // prints 1
timesheetRows[i][p] = moment.utc(timesheetRows[i][p], 'hh:mm').add(Number(hours), 'hours').format('HH:MM');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong formats, `hh` stands for 12 hours and `MM` stands for two digits month number.

Use something like this:

```
moment.utc(timesheetRows[i][p], 'HH:mm').add(Number(hours), 'hours').format('HH:mm');
```

Comment: I feel like thats something i should have been able to spot *facepalm*. Thanks so much for pointing it out! I guess the odd behaviour i described was just some weird side effect which come from using incompatible formats. Thanks again!

Comment: @JonahElbaz Yes, you where getting `:06` because you've used `:MM` (month number) for the output and this is the 6th month.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense!